# Powering Raspberry Pi 4 with a hat

Tags: pi-4, alternative-power

I want to power my Raspberry Pi 4 and a hat separately.

I have a 2200 mAh 3S LiPo and 2x 3.4 V 18560 batteries. If I just cut off the 5 V pin from the Pi and power the Pi from the LiPo batteries, using a convertor, do I have to connect all the ground together? There are 3 volt pins on the hat, so will be there any issue with it?

I am using this [Robot HATS](https://docs.sunfounder.com/projects/picar-s/en/latest/modules.html)

Comment: there is an external power port ... read the documentation about how to use it

Comment: @jsotola I know that there is an external port. You dont seem to understand what i am asking. I have a dc to dc converter to power pi through the gpio pins. But the problem is that  i have a hat which goes on top of the pi.the hat is using another source ( 2* 3.4 volt batteries)  since the hat is using the 3.3v pin should i connect the ground of both the supply ( to the pi and the hat )

Comment: Consider that no one here is a mind reader, so if you don't explain exactly what you want to do, and how you want to do it - there **will be** misunderstanding. It has been said many times that "a picture is worth a thousand words"/ You might consider putting a bit more effort into your question if you hope to get a useful answer. There is also a schematic tool available.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting grounds is never a good idea, you should focus on splitting the "hot" wires. Disclaimer: DON'T DO IT IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.
The hat probably gets power from the Pi, so it should be as simples as finding such traces, interrupting them and rewiring them to the new power source.

Answer (score 0):

Since the pi and the hat are sharing electrical signals, then yes the grounds should be connected together.  However, it is a little dangerous to use separate supplies for different parts of one logical circuit.

**You do this at your own risk.  It is possible that if one voltage is higher than the other, that current may be forced in the wrong direction and destroy your electronics.**